# Fully workable kodi on raspberry pi 3 on raspbian

Tags: raspbian, kodi, raspbian-stretch

I decided to install kodi on raspbian stretch yesterday. It seems that I'm not able to play my local library of TV shows. Kodi has issues playing most of them. Especially x264-tbs mkv files, it plays x264.yify mp4 files but it starts green with no audio for a few seconds than plays them. Other than that, if I try to play another video from my local library, it just shows me a dark screen. After installing kodi, are there any other things I need to do? All of those videos are max 1080p resolution.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your RPi has the ability to play those files at all? Does omxplayer work?

Comment: @Jacobm001, I did fix my issues following this link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=192499 However, the mods deleted it before I had any time to change it to a detailed answer.

Comment: Delete what? Your question is not closed.

Comment: I had answered that I fixed my issues with the link above but they deleted it.